# Power Query: Function to search a column for a list of keywords and return only rows with at least one match

Tags: excel, powerquery

I am making a simple Google-like search function in Power Query.
Let's say I have a column called **Description** in a table called **Database**. The user then inputs some search queries like "dog, cat, animals". I want to filter **Database** for rows that contain at least one of these keywords. They keywords can change each time, depending on what the user types in a named range in Excel.

I know you can filter a column in Power Query for multiple keywords, like this:

```
FilterRows = Table.SelectRows(LastStep, each Text.Contains([English], "dog") or Text.Contains([English], "cat")),
```

but those keywords are static, and the column is also static. I want to be able to control both the keywords and the column name as variables. I think I need to write a function but I am not sure how to start.

Comment: Start with the design of an input method. How will the user enter the criteria and the column? How will the user be informed of the result? If you expect multiple matches the output can't be in a single cell.

Answer (score 1):

Your question requires several moving parts.

First, I would get the keywords from a named range "Keywords" into a table like this:

```
{KeywordTbl}
let
    GetKeywords = if Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Keywords"]}[Content]{0}[Column1] = null then null else Text.Split(Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Keywords"]}[Content]{0}[Column1], ", "),
    ConvertToTable = Table.FromList(GetKeywords,null,{"Keywords"})
in
    ConvertToTable
```

Secondly, store the column name where you want to search in an Excel named range called "ColName". Then pull the named range into Power Query like this:

```
{ColName}
let
    GetColName = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="ColName"]}[Content]{0}[Column1]
in
    GetColName
```

Then I would write a function that takes 4 variables, the table and column you want to look in, and the table and column containing the keywords:

```
{SearchColForKeywords}
(LookInTbl as table, KeywordTbl as table, LookInCol as text, KeywordCol as text) =>
let
    RelativeMerge = Table.AddColumn(LookInTbl, "RelativeJoin", 
        (Earlier) => Table.SelectRows(KeywordTbl, 
            each Text.Contains(Record.Field(Earlier, LookInCol), Record.Field(_, KeywordCol), Comparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase))),
    ExpandRelativeJoin = Table.ExpandTableColumn(RelativeMerge, "RelativeJoin", {KeywordCol}, {"Keywords found"}),
    FilterRows = Table.SelectRows(ExpandRelativeJoin, each [Keywords found] <> null and [Keywords found] <> ""),

    // Concatenate multiple keyword founds line into one line 
    GroupAllData = Table.Group(FilterRows, {"Word ID"}, {{"AllData", each _, type table [First column=text, Second column=text, ... your other columns=text]}}),
    AddCol = Table.AddColumn(GroupAllData, "Keywords found", each [AllData][Keywords found]),
    ExtractValues = Table.TransformColumns(AddCol, {"Keywords found", each Text.Combine(List.Transform(_, Text.From), ", "), type text}),
    DeleteAllData = Table.RemoveColumns(ExtractValues,{"AllData"}),
    MergeQueries = Table.NestedJoin(DeleteAllData, {"Word ID"}, FilterRows, {"Word ID"}, "DeleteAllData", JoinKind.LeftOuter),
    ExpandCols = Table.ExpandTableColumn(MergeQueries, "DeleteAllData", {"First Col name", "Second col name", ... "Your Other column names here"}),
    DeleteKeywordsFound = Table.RemoveColumns(ExpandCols,{"Keywords found"})
in
    DeleteKeywordsFound
```

FYI, half of this function has been developed by a user named lmkeF on PowerBI community. The full discussion is [here](https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Desktop/joinAlgorithm-and-keyEqualityComparers/m-p/1013429#M479534). I merely improved on his solution.

Finally, I will use that function in another query like this:

```
StepName = SearchColForKeywords(MainTbl, KeywordTbl, ColName, "Keywords"),
```

You may customize the 4 variable names.